# Open Mapping Theorem: countexample and example

Tags: functional-analysis

Consider X the space of the integrative functions at $(1, \infty)$, if $f \in X$, $\|f\|=\int_1^\infty |f(t)|dt$.

Let be $T: X \longrightarrow X$ given $T(f)=\frac{f(t)}{t}$.

I've already been able to show that T is linear and limited.

I want to show $T(B(0,1))$ is not open, any suggestions?

Comment: Why not show that $T$ is not surjective? Also, once you use $X$ and another time $E$?

Comment: $D(T)= X$. I just edited.

Answer (score 0):

If a linear map is open, then the image of the open ball is open, thus contains a ball, and by homogeneity, the map is surjective. To show it is not open, you can show that there exists an integrable function that is not the image by $T$ of any function. For example : suppose $g(t) = \frac{1}{t^2}$ is in the image. Then there exists $f$ integrable such that $\forall t \geqslant 1, \frac{f(t)}{t} =g(t)= \frac{1}{t^2}$. Hence, $f$ is the inverse function, that is not integrable on $[1,\infty)$. This is a contradiction.

Comment: Thank's for your comment.